# Windows 8: Show week numbers in mini calendar

Tags: windows, windows-8, calendar, week-number

I want to see week numbers if I click on the mini calendar at the bottom right corner in Windows 8 (and probably 7 I guess). My system is running under Win8.1 Pro.

The image shows what I mean:
http://s7.directupload.net/images/140904/c7a88vg9.jpg

**As one can see, the week numbers on the left side are missing.**
My question is simple: Can this be done by configuring and if yes, where? It seems that not...

Comment: Does this question need to be moved to superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to download a program called: T-Clock, which replaces the standard clock.

A way to get it to work:

1. Download [T-Clock App](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases)
2. Install program
3. After you open the program, on the left hand side make sure (Clock64.exe) is selected.
4. Miscellaneous -> Checked "Use T-Clock's calendar" and "Show week numbers"
5. Hit "Apply" -> "OK"

Then it should work! If any one else has any other ideas I would be curious as well!